# Load image or video when pasting url in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

[image]

I have a textarea, my goal is to type for example there some text, then to paste there an image url(or video url) and to open the image(or video), then to paste another text and so on, to get result like this:

[image]

At the end i need to save al this to database

This is done in laravel blades, and i want to know how can i do this using js or jquery.

Comment: have a look at ckeditor... does what you need and lot more

Comment: thanks, i'l check now.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding what you need is a wysiwyg editor. Something that is not easy to do and requires much more time than I think you expect.

I'd recommend you to go with a tested solution like:

https://www.tiny.cloud/

Comment: but this is not exactly what i need, because when i paste the image url in their editor it is not loaded, it works only when i COPY THE IMAGE, this is not what i need.

Comment: for example facebook works almost like this, the difference is that it is not keepeng the image or video beetween the tex, instead it uploads it separately

Comment: In tinymce for example you can go to insert->image and paste the url. There are many more wysiwyg editors, I would suggest you find one that fits your needs as creating one is not an easy task.

Comment: Thanks i'l try to find.